# Haskell repa --- mapping with indices

Tags: arrays, haskell, repa

Imagine I want to map a function over an array, but the function has a type not just of
    `a -> b`
but
    `a -> Int -> b`
i.e. the function also takes an index. How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer, use `traverse`.

Longer example:

```
import qualified Data.Array.Repa as A
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

arr1 :: A.Array A.DIM2 Double
arr1 = A.fromVector (A.Z A.:. 2 A.:. 3) $ U.fromList [1::Double,2,3,4,5,6]

arr2 :: A.Array A.DIM2 Double
arr2 = A.traverse arr1 id (\lf i@(A.Z A.:. r A.:. c) -> 
                  (lf i) + (fromIntegral r) + (fromIntegral c))
```

`arr1` is a 2x3 matrice.  `traverse` is a function that takes (1) the original array, (2) a function for mapping source indices to target indices, and (3) a function that is given (i) a lookup function into the original array and (ii) an index that returns a new value.

So here `arr2` modifies each of the original elements by adding the row and column indices of that particular entry.

Answer (score 8):

Good question, and it wasn't documented in the [Repa tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell:_A_Repa_Tutorial), so I've updated it with [a new section on traversals](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell:_A_Repa_Tutorial#Mapping.2C_with_indices).

In particular, `traverse` lets you:

- change the shape of the output array
- index any eleemnt
- observe the current element

Meaning you can do things like:

*Replace all eleemnts with their row index*

```
> traverse a id (\_ (Z :. i :. j :. k) -> i) 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

*Multiply an element by its row*

```
> traverse a id (\f (Z :. i :. j :. k) -> f (Z :. i :. j :. k) * i) 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54]
```

And so on. `travese` is *very* powerful, and is also magically parallel.

*Advanced: parallel image desaturation*

[Example from the Repa tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell:_A_Repa_Tutorial#Example:_parallel_image_desaturation)

Answer (score 2):

Use zipWith

```
zipWith (\idx ele -> if even idx then div ele 2 else ele) [0..] xs
```